# Managing a store in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have been trying to improve python combined with Postgres.

At this moment im only sending two values to database which are etc:

```
link = "https://www.mathem.se/varor/vegetarisk-fars/vegofars-fairtrade-1000g-anamma"
store = "mathem"
```

and I do have few options that I want to be able to do with Postgres and that is to fetch all, commit and count.

And here I do have few options such as to check if the link exists already, if its has been deactivated from before, delete the link, get the ID from the product etc etc:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime

import psycopg2

DATABASE_CONNECTION = {
    "host": "testing.com",
    "database": "test",
    "user": "test",
    "password": "test"
}


def execute_fetch_all(query):
    """
    Fetch all queries
    :param query:
    :return:
    """
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONNECTION)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        response = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        return response

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        logger.exception(f"Database error: {error}")
        return


def execute_commit(query):
    """
    Commit database
    :param query:
    :return:
    """
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONNECTION)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        return True

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        logger.exception(f"Database error: {error}")
        return


def execute_count(query):
    """
    Count elements in database
    :param query:
    :return:
    """
    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONNECTION)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        if cursor.rowcount:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            return True
        else:
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            return False

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        logger.exception(f"Database error: {error}")
        return


def check_if_link_exists(store, link):
    """
    Check if link exists
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """
    if execute_count(f"SELECT DISTINCT link FROM public.store_items WHERE store='{store.lower()}' AND link='{link}';"):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def check_if_links_deactivated(store, link):
    """
    Check if link is deactivated
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """
    if execute_count(f"SELECT DISTINCT link FROM public.store_items WHERE store='{store.lower()}' AND link='{link}' AND visible='no';"):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def delete_manual_links(store, link):
    """
    Delete given link
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """
    execute_commit(f"DELETE FROM public.manual_urls WHERE store='{store.lower()}' AND link='{link}';")
    return True


def get_product_id(store, link):
    """
    Get id from database for specific link
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """
    product = execute_fetch_all(f"SELECT DISTINCT id, store, link FROM public.store_items WHERE store='{store.lower()}' AND link='{link}' AND visible='yes';")
    return {"id": product[0][0], "store": product[0][1], "link": product[0][2]}

def get_all_links(store):
    """
    Return all links in database
    :param store:
    :return:
    """
    cur = execute_fetch_all(f"SELECT DISTINCT id, link FROM public.store_items WHERE store='{store.lower()}' AND visible='yes';")
    return [{"id": links[0], "link": links[1]} for links in cur]



def check_if_store_exists(store):
    """
    Check if the store exists in database
    :param store:
    :return:
    """
    if execute_count(f"SELECT DISTINCT store FROM public.store_config WHERE store='{store.lower()}';"):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def register_store(store):
    """
    Register the store
    :param store:
    :return:
    """
    if check_if_store_exists(store=store) is False:
        execute_commit(f"INSERT INTO public.store_config (store) VALUES ('{store.lower()}');")
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I wonder if there is a way to maybe even short the code by alot or to also improve when using postgres combined with Python since it is new for me still but I do see potential that I might be able to shorter the code quite alot here

If there is any missing information, please let me know in comments and I will try my best to give the information that I might have forgot to add here

Comment: What about using an ORM like sqlalchemy?

Comment: Hi @hjpotter92 - Im actually not sure what is that?

Comment: https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Hmm im not sure what that is, is it like a replacement of postgres?

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie ORM (like SQLAlchemy) is not a replacement, it is an abstraction layer over PostgreSQL or another db server

Comment: @n1k9 Oh I see, that would also work but it is abit out of my knowledge and I think I would need a small example out of the code I provided to know/understand how it would look for my case if that is possible? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Injection

```
f"SELECT DISTINCT link FROM public.store_items WHERE store='{store.lower()}' AND link='{link}';"
```

is wide open to injection attacks. `psycopg2` has excellent support for parameters in prepared statements; use that instead of string formatting.

### Hard-coded credentials

`DATABASE_CONNECTION` needs to be externalized to somewhere secure in the operating system environment, for a handful of reasons including protecting the password, and keeping reconfiguration easy. This can take the form of environmental variables or a config file.

### Context management

This block:

```
    connection = psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONNECTION)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    response = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
```

has a number of issues:

- You're opening and closing a new connection every time you do a fetch. Connections are expensive and should be longer-lived.
- You need to replace explicit `close` with the use of a context-management `with` statement.
- Your `except` effectively swallows all exceptions and returns `None` if there's a failure. That behaviour should not be baked into `execute_fetch_all` and should exist outside, at the caller level instead. This is true for `execute_count` and `execute_commit` as well.

### Explicit commit

`execute_commit` does not benefit from `commit()` in its current form. Read this for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880309/what-does-autocommit-mean-in-postgresql-and-psycopg2 - autocommit is the default.

### Existence checks

```
SELECT DISTINCT
```

is not the best way to check for existence. Instead, consider use of the actual PostgreSQL `exists` clause.

### Dictionary construction

Don't do this:

```
[{"id": links[0], "link": links[1]} for links in cur]
```

yourself.

Read https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor for the built-in alternative.

### Booleans

```
if x is False:
```

should be

```
if not x:
```

and

```
if x:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

should be

```
return bool(x)
```

or, if you're comparing a count, more explicitly:

```
return x > 0
```

Comment: Hi! I forgot to mention that this script will only be locally PC and will not be uploaded anywhere in the web! So only me will be able to do anything with this script! :) - About the database connection, I was not sure what would be the best option, etc, if I run etc 100 scripts where each script has a import of database.py, Wouldn't that mean that all of them would be connected to the database at the same time and hit the maximium connection? Thats the reason I have a close() at this moment but might be wrong too!

Comment: _this script will only be locally PC_ - For learning purposes, you should still strive for production-quality code. Get into good habits sooner rather than later.

Comment: _all of them would be connected to the database at the same time and hit the maximium connection_ - Sure; but that would still potentially happen even if you close your connection more often. It's still possible for there to be 100 concurrent calls to your fetch routine. The solution is not to close the connection more often; it's to centralize connection management into a smaller number of processes with connection pools.

Comment: That is true. However im not sure how to solve that issue in that case where I can have a connection pool. What should it actually happend if you etc have 150 scripts where all of them are connected to the db, My idea and reason I did is that I just wanted to connect -> to my add/update/delete to the db -> close it. To never reach the connection issue. But I assume as you mentioned this is not the correct way and im not sure what else I can do from here code-wise :(

Comment: If you're running 150 scripts that all connect to the database at once, you have bigger problems.

Comment: If you actually need something like this, you need to revisit your architecture.

Comment: Hmm im pretty sure you are right, however I do not use the database constantly aswell for all scripts but I do agree what you mean. Im sure the problem I might have would belongs to stackoverflow. In the meanwhile I tried to find any information about "prepared statements" but did not find any good examples besides some stackoverflow questions.